# Delphi/Indy 10 - Sending a text or HTML email with attachments adds an attachment for the text (body) itself

Tags: email, delphi, attachment, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

For **years**, we've been using Indy 10 to send emails (text, not HTML) with one or more PDF attached to it and we **never** had any problem.

Recently (maybe since Tokyo release 3 ?), our customers noticed that the text part of the email (body) is now an attachment and not part of the email itself.

I've searched the Internet for solutions, and everything I tested did not fix this problem.

I tried some of the solutions proposed on StackOverflow by Remy Lebeau with no success.

[image: The body is an attachment]

Here's the code (based on a post found on StackOverflow)

```
procedure TForm1.btnSendEmailClick(Sender: TObject);

var
   smtp   : TIdSMTP;
   msg    : TidMessage;
   builder: TIdMessageBuilderHtml;

begin
   msg := TidMessage.Create(nil);

   try
      builder := TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create();

      try
         // FIsBodyHtml IS FALSE
         if FIsBodyHtml then begin
            builder.Html.Text   := edText.Lines.Text;
            builder.HtmlCharSet := 'utf-8';
            builder.HtmlContentTransfer := 'quoted-printable';
         end else begin
            builder.PlainText.Text := edText.Lines.Text;;
            builder.PlainTextCharSet := 'utf-8';
            builder.PlainTextContentTransfer := 'quoted-printable';
         end;

         // Add attached file here
         if (edFile.Text <> '') and FileExists(edFile.Text) then begin
            builder.Attachments.Add(edFile.Text);
         end;

         builder.FillMessage(msg);
      finally
         builder.Free;
      end;

      msg.From.Name    := 'From name here';
      msg.From.Address := 'From email address here';
      msg.Subject      := edSubject.Text;

      msg.Recipients.EmailAddresses := edEMail.Text;
      // msg.CCList.EmailAddresses     := CCAddresses;
      // msg.BccList.EmailAddresses    := BCCAddresses;

      smtp := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);

      try
         smtp.Host     := 'Host IP here';
         // Smtp.UseTLS   := utNoTLSSupport;
         smtp.Port     := 25;
         // smtp.Username := '';
         // smtp.Password := '';
         // smtp.AuthType := satDefault;

         smtp.Connect();

         try
           smtp.Send(msg);
         finally
           smtp.Disconnect;
         end;

      finally
         smtp.Free();
      end;
   finally
     msg.Free();
   end;

   ShowMessage('EMail with attachment sent.');
end;
```

RAW data BEFORE our service provider changed something :

```
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Envelope-From: stephans@xys.com
Return-Path: <stephans@xyz.com>
Received: from alt44.smtp-out.videotron.ca (alt44.smtp-out.videotron.ca [23.233.128.31])
    by mail124c7.megamailservers.com (8.14.9/8.13.1) with ESMTP id w8IE2EaJ031620
    for <stephans@xyz.com>; Tue, 18 Sep 2018 10:02:16 -0400
Received: from STEPHANS (99.99.99.99])
    by Videotron with SMTP
    id 2GZxgRaQACk662GZygKZJC; Tue, 18 Sep 2018 10:02:14 -0400
Message-ID: <0575a0d8ec54a7560be55a121df5deb7@smtp.videotron.ca>
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.3 cv=I/dLuuog c=1 sm=1 tr=0
 a=dE52as2XWJrk6k5j72Z8kA==:117 a=dE52as2XWJrk6k5j72Z8kA==:17
 a=9DvhAHx2yrWFMPxQWpQA:9 a=ddwX9jWfLaJL_gwCi7EA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10
 a=x4g3fk4yahj5Vy8AyNEA:9 a=n3BslyFRqc0A:10 a=QGevMSd5eboA:10
From: "Stephan St-Denis" <stephans@xyz.com>
Subject: Sending an email with an attachment
To: stephans@xyz.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="sYOn6pS43NerAC6V2swiiWL68DI9=_SoRR"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 18 Sep 2018 10:02:11 -0400
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfKOiVw8oDz+nXCTnbMSWSKyXaMU478wM3VDSWQBABhzflbVLGHq70qeoq1ROGHLKj2lDQPx1LLDrcmvbcOtrdhj4j8xx2kLFmh3LfsDxgKpXpd44Lyvy
 UHG4KDKHPNZy4UAAlgA05WwJ7eshsOWamzFhqA3QrXuliQNQVttLQNbhbjg2fqOR387/8VrwqftGFg==
X-CTCH-Spam: Unknown
X-CTCH-VOD: Unknown
X-CTCH-RefID: str=0001.0A020201.5BA10569.0015,ss=1,re=0.000,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,vtr=str,vl=0,cl=1,cld=1,fgs=0
X-CSC: 0
X-CHA: v=2.3 cv=TIBrtWta c=1 sm=1 tr=0 a=C7+rQaujYuxIIavLKnSTDg==:117
    a=dE52as2XWJrk6k5j72Z8kA==:17 a=dueAcN81E1cA:10 a=JBFolyDoGHsA:10
    a=9DvhAHx2yrWFMPxQWpQA:9 a=ddwX9jWfLaJL_gwCi7EA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10
    a=x4g3fk4yahj5Vy8AyNEA:9 a=n3BslyFRqc0A:10 a=QGevMSd5eboA:10
X-WHL: LR
X-EsetId: 37303A298E2AB560627366

This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--sYOn6pS43NerAC6V2swiiWL68DI9=_SoRR
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="Attachment"

This is the text that will be sent along with the attached file. This =
email is in text only format and not HTML.

The text should not be attached but should be part of the email.

--sYOn6pS43NerAC6V2swiiWL68DI9=_SoRR
Content-Type: application/pdf;
    name="Embarcadero.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="Embarcadero.pdf"
Content-ID: <Embarcadero.pdf>
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--sYOn6pS43NerAC6V2swiiWL68DI9=_SoRR--
```

RAW data **AFTER** our service provider changed something

```
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Envelope-From: stephans@xyz.com
Return-Path: <stephans@xyz.com>
Received: from alt14.smtp-out.videotron.ca (alt14.smtp-out.videotron.ca [135.19.0.27])
    by mail141c7.megamailservers.com (8.14.9/8.13.1) with ESMTP id w8JCvhOr015926
    for <stephans@xyz.com>; Wed, 19 Sep 2018 08:57:45 -0400
Received: from STEPHANS ([99.99.99.99])
    by Videotron with SMTP
    id 2c34gzZ4bMdc62c35g1R7X; Wed, 19 Sep 2018 08:57:43 -0400
Message-ID: <5283e5cb2949102f2e22f509477dacaa@smtp.videotron.ca>
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.3 cv=PoG9kTE3 c=1 sm=1 tr=0
 a=dE52as2XWJrk6k5j72Z8kA==:117 a=dE52as2XWJrk6k5j72Z8kA==:17
 a=9DvhAHx2yrWFMPxQWpQA:9 a=PyNp0P9dkJ191ZjJjSMA:9 a=ddwX9jWfLaJL_gwCi7EA:9
 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=x4g3fk4yahj5Vy8AyNEA:9 a=n3BslyFRqc0A:10 a=QGevMSd5eboA:10
From: "Stephan St-Denis" <stephans@xyz.com>
Subject: Sending an email with an attachment
To: stephans@xyz.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="2oubkSu12F4FBVsrQ1qmkA=_rIo3IvFYNM"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 08:57:42 -0400
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfBPFtECskEptewv8r0bLuVgVpcybKuamQgK0q+veOE3mDcPmuU0j2BlwRMolPNl4KeDVRtyCVMVmkK8N5jufk8voKnE1l6SnBAVceHp6p6Ohg6KTOIp1
 srRHBcfqKq4iTOHzsbt4HfC5vzAuQXm6H3d2pHYX2JNz8N1Pq6ze3mdvvacTtuYNEbvI0Ny8ev9LrA==
X-CTCH-Spam: Unknown
X-CTCH-VOD: Unknown
X-CTCH-RefID: str=0001.0A02020C.5BA247CA.0005,ss=1,re=0.000,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,vtr=str,vl=0,cl=1,cld=1,fgs=0
X-CSC: 0
X-CHA: v=2.3 cv=feyDNXYF c=1 sm=1 tr=0 a=csAb9/S9F4eoTzVqV71Dmw==:117
    a=dE52as2XWJrk6k5j72Z8kA==:17 a=WrA80cmexyYA:10 a=JBFolyDoGHsA:10
    a=9DvhAHx2yrWFMPxQWpQA:9 a=PyNp0P9dkJ191ZjJjSMA:9 a=ddwX9jWfLaJL_gwCi7EA:9
    a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=x4g3fk4yahj5Vy8AyNEA:9 a=n3BslyFRqc0A:10
    a=QGevMSd5eboA:10
X-WHL: LR
X-EsetId: 37303A298E2AB560627264

This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--2oubkSu12F4FBVsrQ1qmkA=_rIo3IvFYNM
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="DhsioUcQxViR3rGTk=_q17PSufSL3rps7M"

--DhsioUcQxViR3rGTk=_q17PSufSL3rps7M
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

An HTML viewer is required to see this message

--DhsioUcQxViR3rGTk=_q17PSufSL3rps7M
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

This is the text that will be sent along with the attached file. This =
email is in text only format and not HTML.

The text should not be attached but should be part of the email.

--DhsioUcQxViR3rGTk=_q17PSufSL3rps7M--

--2oubkSu12F4FBVsrQ1qmkA=_rIo3IvFYNM
Content-Type: application/pdf;
    name="Embarcadero.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="Embarcadero.pdf"
Content-ID: <Embarcadero.pdf>
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--2oubkSu12F4FBVsrQ1qmkA=_rIo3IvFYNM--
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, and I see nothing wrong with the code. Please show the raw email data that `TIdMessage` is actually generating. I suspect the problem is going to be on the receiver's end instead (buggy reader, etc)

Comment: Thank you Remy for your precious time and for answering my question. This morning, I sent myself an email in order to show you the RAW email data and I don't know what happened during the night, but the body is now shown correctly (not attached to the message). It looks like our service provider changed something on their side during the night (software update ?). Many of our customers have the same provider. Could it be related ? Probably. I'll show you the RAW data of the same email before and after the change.

Comment: After contacting one of our customers who have the same service provider, it seems that the problem have been solved during the night. They sent us an email and everything is OK. We spent countless hours on this case. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: in your first example, the plain text's `Content-Disposition` has a `filename` attribute that doesn't belong. In your second example, that attribute is missing

Comment: **Remy** - Exactly. The first example was _before_ our service provider modified something. The second example is the exact same email, but sent the day after. Strange isn't it ? Thanks again for your precious time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it can't be reproduced anymore

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. I'm studying the above example. I do think another blog post on the correct use of TIdMessageBuilderHtml would be great on the indy blog.   It does appear very difficult to see what can be generated and accepted by most email clients.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The problem is reproducable with Microsoft Mail. I have a multipart/alternative message. When Content-Disposition: inline is added to the textparts (IdMessageClient.SendBody does this), Mail shows two ATT000 attachments (one for the plaintext part, one for the html part). Microsoft Mail is extremely picky about Content-Disposition. A mail send with Outlook 2016 for example will not show inline images because the "Content-Disposion: inline" is missing for that image attachment.

Comment: I created a class based on your example. I use it and have no problems. It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same sort of problem with Microsoft Mail. It is caused by the "Content-Disposition: inline" line in the text part which causes MS Mail to show the text part as a downloadable attachment. Removing the Content-Disposition line fixes this but requires you to modify TIdMessageClient.SendBody. Frankly I think MS Mail is to blame.